# Get specific id of span

Tags: html, jquery

so I need to get id of span where is input of checkbox.. so if checkbox is checked I need to get specific id of span where is that checked checkbox.

my code

HTML:

```
<div id="APs">
    <span id="59" name="4"><input type="checkbox"> <b>[Site: 4 | ID: 59]</b> - something<br></span>
    <span id="60" name="4"><input type="checkbox"> <b>[Site: 4 | ID: 60]</b> - something<br></span>
    <span id="275" name="4"><input type="checkbox"> <b>[Site: 4 | ID: 275]</b> - something<br></span>
    <span id="2903" name="4"><input type="checkbox"> <b>[Site: 4 | ID: 2903]</b> - something<br></span>
    <span id="3417" name="4"><input type="checkbox"> <b>[Site: 4 | ID: 3417]</b> - something<br></span>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).on("change", ":checkbox", function () {
   if ($(this).is(":checked")) 
   {
      const apid = $("#APs span").attr("id");
      console.log(apid);

      //another lines of code

   }
}
```

This code only choose only first span even if I click on second checkbox it will still log id 59.

I need to get that id because I am getting datas from JSON what is on url but I need that id to get right data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you select all `#APs span` elements, not the one related to the checkbox which was selected. When you call jQuery's `attr()` method on an object containing a collection it will only read the property from the first element.

To change this behaviour, use the `this` keyword along with the `closest()` selector to get the parent `span` of the checkbox which raised the `change` event.

```js
$(document).on("change", ":checkbox", function() {
  let $cb = $(this);
  if ($cb.is(":checked")) {
    const apid = $cb.closest('span').prop("id");
    console.log(apid);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="APs">
  <span id="59" name="4"><input type="checkbox"> <b>[Site: 4 | ID: 59]</b> - something<br></span>
  <span id="60" name="4"><input type="checkbox"> <b>[Site: 4 | ID: 60]</b> - something<br></span>
  <span id="275" name="4"><input type="checkbox"> <b>[Site: 4 | ID: 275]</b> - something<br></span>
  <span id="2903" name="4"><input type="checkbox"> <b>[Site: 4 | ID: 2903]</b> - something<br></span>
  <span id="3417" name="4"><input type="checkbox"> <b>[Site: 4 | ID: 3417]</b> - something<br></span>
</div>
```